# Change select field options in client script in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a client script runs on Suitelet.
On Suitelet we have a sublist which has many select columns.
Let's say we have *Select 1* and *Select 2*.
*Select 2* options should be different if you change the option in *Select 1*.
Could this be done in Client Script? or in that Suitelet?
Any help would be appreciated.
`

```
var select1= sublist.addField({
    id: 'custpage_select1',
    label: 'Select1',
    type: ui.FieldType.SELECT
    });
var select2= sublist.addField({
    id: 'custpage_select2',
    label: 'Select2',
    type: ui.FieldType.SELECT
    });
```

`
In client script when the field is changed, I want to change options of Select 2 depend on Select 1.

```
function fieldChanged(scriptContext){
    if(scriptContext.fieldId=="custpage_select1"){
    let page = currentRecord.get();
    var select2 = page.getField({fieldID:"custpage_select2"});
    select2.removeSelectOption({value:"value1"});
    }
}
```

But this shows me an error that

> Cannot read properties of null

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the `N/currentRecord` module in your client script with `getField()` and `removeSelectOption()`.

```
let page = currentRecord.get();

const select2 = page.getField({
    fieldId: 'custpage_select2'
});

select2.removeSelectOption({
    value: 'option1'
});
```

Comment: Thank you but what if it is sublist column? because when I try to *getField* it shows me an error

Comment: I have added the code snippet but it throws me an error

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4637583684.html

Comment: Use `getSublistField` in that case.